# How can I repeat only a portion of an image in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, html-canvas

So I'm trying to repeat a *portion* of my spritesheet as a background. So far, I have attempted this:

```
var canvas = $("#board")[0],
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    sprite = new Image();
    sprite.src = "spritesheet.png";
sprite.onload = function(){
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(spriteBg, "repeat");
    ctx.fillRect(0, 25, 500, 500);
}
```

As you can see, it repeat the whole image, not just a part of it, and I just can't figure out how to do that last part.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761670/multiple-image-patterns-in-2d-context-of-html5-canvas

Comment: Mobil: If that solved your problem, you should post your conclusions as an answer. Then others with the same problem can find it too.

Comment: @KeithThomas Yea sorry. Posted my answer now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This'll do! :D

```
var sprite     = new Image(),
    sprite.src = "spritesheet.png",
    texture    = {y: 42, x: 2*14},
    ptrn       = generatePattern(sprite, texture.x, texture.y);
ctx.fillStyle  = ctx.createPattern(ptrn, "repeat");
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
```

Thanks to @KeithThomas for linking to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761670/multiple-image-patterns-in-2d-context-of-html5-canvas

Comment: I'm confused by this answer, what is the generatePattern() method? I can't find any info on this online...did you mean to use createPattern() twice? Can you pass the x and y coordinates to this method instead of just "repeat"?